# How do I display an image from URL in C#?

Tags: c#, image, url

I heard that framework 2.0 supports image url but I cant find it. Is there any way to display  an image directly from Url in C#? (Desktop Application)

Normally my followed way is that I download image after return an image. Here is my code.. But I dont want to follow that kind of way. So I am looking for a method which doesnt use Httpwebrequest or like that..

```
  public Image DownloadImage(string _URL)
        {
            Image _tmpImage = null;

            try
            {
                // Open a connection
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest _HttpWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_URL);

                _HttpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

                // You can also specify additional header values like the user agent or the referer: (Optional)
                _HttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
                _HttpWebRequest.Referer = "http://www.google.com/";

                // set timeout for 20 seconds (Optional)
                _HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000;

                // Request response:
                System.Net.WebResponse _WebResponse = _HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                // Open data stream:
                System.IO.Stream _WebStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                // convert webstream to image
                _tmpImage = Image.FromStream(_WebStream);

                // Cleanup
                _WebResponse.Close();
                _WebResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception _Exception)
            {
                // Error
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
                return null;
            }

            return _tmpImage;
        }
```

I am looking for an alternative way. I dont know what can be.. ? I want to learn how can I handle that..

Comment: You said what you _don't_ want to do, but what exactly _do_ you want to use?

Comment: I said that I am looking for another way.. Is not important what is that.. I just dont want to use http.

Comment: Another way to get an image from the web, without using the web? What exactly are you looking for in the alternative? What's so bad with your current approach?

Comment: as I told, I heard that there is a method which supports get image from url by framework 2.0 or up. But I dont know what is that.. I read it somewhere.

Comment: Are you talking about `WebClient`? Where did you hear? Why not look there?

Comment: Its not a weblicent or like that. Think a method like fromUrl instead of "fromFile". and there wasnt any informtion about that. Just written by someperson

Comment: Which makes this question very vague. You are asking for "something" else without giving any parameters for what you are looking for (except for "not this").

Comment: @Oded I think he’s asking for a method analogous to `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile`, just for URIs. As far as I’m aware, there’s none (well, there’s `Image.FromStream` but he explicitly didn’t want that, since it still requires a web client).

Comment: `PictureBox.Load(String url)` that is the new direct framework 2.0 support. Tested in my own applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this code

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.yourSite.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "YourImagegif", 
myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

Comment: it looks nice but it still downloads :) I understood there is not any way to do it.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you want to display an image url on a desktop application.
So you have to download image before.
use WebClient by calling DownloadFile method

Comment: Thank you for answer.. But Yes I know then I am looking for another way..

Answer (score 1):

try to use picturebox controls.
 use this for load image from web

```
string imageLink="http://where.is/image.tld";
pictureBox1.ImageLocation= imageLink;
```

create a form with textbox,datagridview,picturebox and button;
set datagrid selection mode to fullrow select.
use this code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string imageLink= textBox1.Text;
           try
                    {
                        int i;
                        i = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value = imageLink;


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("error");
                    }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            string img = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();


            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = img;
        }
```

Comment: I know that thank you but I will use images in gridview which I add column as image

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this topic 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/312a7fb2-9411-450a-8032-ee169397fd96
may be it's what you looking for

Comment: yes its  a nice method thank you :)